# I copy-pasted in another file exactly the same hair. Why did it explode in the second file?

Tags: armature, bones, pose-mode

[image: First file]

[image: First file]

[image: First file]

[image: First file]

[image: Second file]

[image: Second file]
[image: Second file]
[image: Second file]
I copy-pasted in another file exactly the same hair.   Why did it explode in the second file ?

Comment: Thank you for your research !